# What contests/datasets for expertise retrieval ?

Tags: dataset, information-retrieval

Expertise retrieval is a difficult task to define. [This article](http://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/INR-024) describes the task of expert finding as "finding the right person with the appropriate skills and knowledge". Applications exist in academic domains, enterprises, web forums, etc. Do you know opened challenges or opened datasets to practice in this field ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [StackExchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps). Or in more detail, for questions with answers, or categories, retrieve the users who are most likely to answer them well.